# Visitor Timezone conversion from UTC to Local and vice versa in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, datetime, timezone

I have select Timezone box, if I select any timezone, I want to display date and time of visitor selected timezone in JSP, but it is taking as local machine Timezone by default. Please any one can suggest me, how can I do this.

Comment: What date/time API do you use? Is it `java.util.Date`? Avoid it as soon as possible, if you are concerned with/interested in time zone(s). Look for other APIs like Joda-Time or Java Time available in Java 8.

Comment: Hi Tiny, Thanks for your suggestions.. How can i do in Jsp level

Comment: Do you happen to use [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)? Fortunately, Joda-Time has a nice [support](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/contrib/jsptags/) for JSP ([user guide](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/contrib/jsptags/userguide.html)).